# For computational problems that do no I/O and access no shared data, Ncpu + 1 threads yields optimal throughput?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, cpu

Java Concurrency in Practice:

> For computational problems like this that do no I/O and access no shared data, Ncpu or Ncpu + 1 threads yield optimal throughput; more threads do not help, and may in fact degrade performance as the threads compete for CPU and memory resources.

I have never seen this Ncpu + 1 recommendation, it's always Ncpu. Why Ncpu + 1 is also optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is presented couple of chapters later:

> Even compute-intensive threads occasionally take a page fault or pause for some other reason, so an “extra” runnable thread prevents CPU cycles from going unused when this happens.

Anyway, not very nice to explain presented concept about 100 pages later.